# Google Sheets: HELP! Can I resolve circular dependency without turning on iteritive calculation?

Tags: google-sheets, circular-dependency

Somehow, I'm getting a circular dependency error.  My system appears to be pretty linear -- I've looked everywhere and I can't figure out where my sequence of functions is looping back into itself in a way that would cause the error.

I tried turning on "iterative calculation", but it seems to resolve some issues, but also prevents some columns from recalculating when the data changes.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

1. Use checkboxes to select the items I want to sell to my customers.
2. View incoming orders from my customers
3. Recalculate my stock number, based on the incoming orders.

The issue appears to stem from my =INDEX(MATCH(MATCH formulas (highlighted yellow in the sheet).

Here's my sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pdkgltorBEGpgG2mPV1iINBBFlhFxQsBAy1-rv8klVY/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone find a way to resolve the circular dependency without turning on iterative calculation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution, though I do not completely understand why it worked.  I created a "helper" tab where I used a query to show only items with checked checkboxes.  I then used an array to show the incoming orders.  On my original list of items, I used =INDEX(MATCH(MATCH to grab my order data from the "helper" tab.  I didn't have to use iterative calculation and my circular dependency error is gone.  Hot diggity!  :-)